# Game Development Using IIFEs - Code Seperation

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, logic

So, I'm currently learning how to use Javascript for Canvas game development. After seeing the method used in several examples, and having read the benefits, I started shifting my code over into IIFEs.

However, at the moment, all of my code is in a single IIFE. What I want to do is begin separating my code in to individual files.

The part I'm stuck on, however, is how to allow each IIFE function see data that's in another. I don't really understand how this works.

My full code is in this fiddle, https://jsfiddle.net/473z1g2t/1/, whilst a sample of my code is below;

```
(function(){
    var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
    var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

    function Ball(x, y, radius, color){
        /* .. */
    }

    function Paddle(x, y){
        /* .. */
    }

    var ball = new Ball((canvas.width / 2), canvas.height - 60, 10, 'black');
    var paddle = new Paddle((canvas.width / 2) - 20, 550);

    function initCanvas(){
        canvas.addEventListener('click', function(){
            if(!ball.active)
                ball.active = true;
            else
                ball.active = false;
        });

        canvas.addEventListener('mousemove', function(e){

        });
    }

    initCanvas();

    function Update(){
        Draw();
        requestAnimationFrame(Update);

        if(ball.active){
            /* .. */
        }
    }
    function Draw(){
        ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
        ball.draw();
        paddle.draw();
    }

    requestAnimationFrame(Update);
})();
```

### TLDR

I want to separate my Paddle and Ball logic from the rest of the application (and possibly the canvasInit function too). What is the preferred method of going about this? I know I can pass parameters to these functions, but what do I pass between them?

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I understand from your code, you don't actually have communication between the pad and the ball.

So you can just move the classes into another file and have a master file (the canvas one) which orchestrate the elements on the screen.

```

```
(function(canvas, ctx) {
    function Ball(x, y, radius, color){
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.r = radius;
        this.c = color;
        this.vx = -3;
        this.vy = -3;
        this.active = false;

        this.draw = function(){
            ctx.beginPath();
            ctx.arc(this.x, this.y, this.r, 0, Math.PI*2);
            ctx.fill();
            ctx.closePath();
        }
    }
})(canvas, ctx);
```

```

You can either do that and share the globals canvas and ctx or you can send canvas and ctx as parameters in Ball/Paddle constructors

Bu if you do want to share data between them, you can do it during the orchestration calling method with specific parameters.

Comment: Thanks, this does help! - although I'm still not sure I fully understand what's happening here with canvas, ctx in the constructor and the return. More reading is definitely required!

Comment: Ignore this. Since you are defining them into another IIFE, they are not global and therefore it is better to send as parameters.

You can try to use some parameter builder pattern like new `Ball().withContext(ctx)` to be more readable

Something like this:

    Ball.prototype.withContext = function(c) {
        this.ctx = c;
        return this;
    }

Comment: I have just tried this, and receive undefined errors for ctx and canvas. Am I missing something? I've also tried returning them in the main.js file.

Comment: Can you give more code? did you change the draw method from `ctx.beginPath();` to `this.ctx.beginPath();` ?

Comment: I've built a minimal demo to begin restructuring my code. You can find it here - https://jsfiddle.net/h7b3wbfe/ - all I'm trying to do at the moment is get the canvas to draw from another file

Comment: The way you did there doesn't make much sense. It seems that you are trying to separate something that is very coupled to each other.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/106609/discussion-between-lewis-and-rafael-grillo).